# vba to dynamically delete checkboxes from a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet where I'm adding CheckBoxes if a range is not empty.
But also what I want is that dynamically if this range decreases its value (goes from 5 to 3, for example) I want to delete these other CheckBoxes.

For example, I have 4 filled rows and my code added 4 checkboxes:
[image]

But then I deleted 2 rows so I was expecting that these checkboxes were deleted too, but when I run the code again I still get these checkboxes:
[image]

This is what I've tried so far and part of it I took from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965655/6088173) answer, but it didn't work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddCheckbox()
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim obj As OLEObject, cb As MSForms.CheckBox

Set ws = Sheets("Consulta")
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To lastrow
    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("E" & i, "J" & i)) Then
        For Each rng In ws.Range("D" & i)
            ws.OLEObjects.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.Height
        Next
    ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Range("E" & i, "J" & i)) Then
        For Each obj In ws.OLEObjects
        If TypeOf obj.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            Set cb = obj.Object
            If cb.ShapeRange.Item(1).TopLeftCell.Address = _
                ActiveCell.Address Then obj.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Any suggestions will help! I truly believe that the problem is with this part below:

```
If cb.ShapeRange.Item(1).TopLeftCell.Address = _
    ActiveCell.Address Then obj.Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not great but does work:

```
Sub AddCheckbox()

    Const RW_START As Long = 5
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, o As Object, v
    Dim obj As OLEObject, cb 'As MSForms.CheckBox

    Set ws = Sheets("Consulta")
    lastrow = 500 'ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    '^^^ not sure what would be the best approach here...

    For i = RW_START To lastrow

        If Application.CountA(ws.Range("E" & i & ":J" & i)) > 0 Then
            With ws.Range("D" & i)
                'not already added a checkbox?
                If Len(.Value) = 0 Then
                    Set o = ws.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", _
                                Left:=.Left, Top:=.Top, _
                                Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height)
                    'create a name for the checkbox and link it to the cell
                    v = Application.Max(ws.Cells(RW_START, "D").Resize(1000, 1))
                    v = v + 1
                    o.Name = "cbx_" & v
                    .Value = v
                    .Font.Color = vbWhite
                    Debug.Print i, v
                End If
            End With
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Shapes(ws.Range("D" & i).Value).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            ws.Range("D" & i).Value = ""
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I did tried something similar to that but it didn't work as I expected

Comment: `lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row` if there's no content in Col E then the empty rows will not get processed

Comment: I see that... I used the same example as I printed here and nothing changed... It supposed to delete the checkboxes if the corresponding row is now empty

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I got `Runtime Error -214724809 (80070057)` on line `ws.Shapes(ws.Range("D" & i).Value).Delete`

Comment: That's what the `On Error Resume Next` is for - do you have your VB set up on "Break on all errors" though ?  That would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Yeah, I've changed to Break On Unhandled Errors and it worked! Thanks, I could understand everything... I guess my problem was everytime I run my code it "subscribes" the checkboxes and as I didn't rename them they always have a new name and I couldn't find them to delete later because the name has changed. May not be that but it was my first thought.