# Excel VBA - Removing duplicate rows that contain checkboxes (duplicates from a single column)

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have a spreadsheet with checkboxes in one of the columns and I would like to have a macro that removes duplicate rows (with checkboxes for those rows).

I currently have the following code which does exactly what I need, however checkboxes do not delete with rows. I am using excel 2010 with form control checkboxes which are set up to "move but don't size with cells".

Could someone help me add a line of code which would delete the checkbox when deleting a row.

Here is my current macro:

```
Sub CleanSheet()

Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long
Dim DelRange As Range

With Worksheets("Scale Costs")
    LastRowcheck = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For n1 = 1 To LastRowcheck
        If .Cells(n1, 1).Value = Cells(n1 + 1, 1).Value Then
            If DelRange Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRange = .Rows(n1)
            Else
                Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, .Rows(n1))
            End If
        End If
    Next n1

    If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete
End With
End Sub
```

I found a line of code online that can delete the checkbox in the selected cell, but I'm not sure how to add it to the macro I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
Sub DeleteCheckboxFromRow(ws As Worksheet, r As Range)
    Dim obj As OLEObject, ck As CheckBox

    For Each obj In ws.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(obj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            If Not Intersect(obj.TopLeftCell, r.EntireRow) Is Nothing Then obj.Delete
        End If
    Next

    For Each ck In ws.CheckBoxes
        If Not Intersect(ck.TopLeftCell, r.EntireRow) Is Nothing Then ck.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Took me a few minutes to figure out how to call this inside my existing function (because i'm quite new to VBA), but I managed to figure it out. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You should watch this series:[Excel VBA Introduction - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  Thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

put the line in the delete code

```
If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then
    ' delete checkbox here
    DelRange.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried adding the code that I found (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965551/macro-to-delete-a-checkbox-from-a-certain-cell), but I can't get it to work. The checkboxes still will not delete.